# Interview : Maximum path sum in a 2-D matrix using recursion. Recovery of the path

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, matrix

**Question**

Given a m x n grid filled with non-negative numbers, find a path from top left to bottom right which *maximizes* the sum of all numbers along its path.

Note: You can only move either down or right at any point in time.

**Approach**

I've just approached this with naive recursion, and the code I wrote for this looks like below.
The problem I have is that I'm unable to figure out how to recover the path taken in the grid. I passed in a vector by reference (path) so I can recover the path for each recursive call.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int getMaxPath(vector<vector<int> > Grid, int r, int c, vector<int> &path)
{
    if((r > Grid.size()-1) || (c > Grid[0].size()-1))
        return 0;

    if(r==Grid.size()-1 && c==Grid[0].size()-1){
        return Grid[r][c];
    }

    int rs = getMaxPath(Grid, r, c+1, path);
    int ds = getMaxPath(Grid, r+1, c, path);


    return max(rs,ds)+Grid[r][c];

}

int maxPath(vector<vector<int> > Grid, vector<int> &path)
{
    return getMaxPath(Grid, 0, 0, path);
}

int main() {

    vector<vector<int> > mat{{5,0,8,12}, {11,16,9,13},{10,2,15,300},{3,14,18,19}};
    vector<int>path;

    path.push_back(mat[0][0]);
    int result = maxPath(mat, path);
    cout << result << endl;

    for(auto i : path)
        cout << i << " " << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

As one can see, the main part of the code is the recursion, and I'd put the line to recover the path like so (*commented*)--

```
int getMaxPath(vector<vector<int> > Grid, int r, int c, vector<int> &path)
{
    if((r > Grid.size()-1) || (c > Grid[0].size()-1))
        return 0;

    if(r==Grid.size()-1 && c==Grid[0].size()-1){
        return Grid[r][c];
    }

    int rs = getMaxPath(Grid, r, c+1, path);
    int ds = getMaxPath(Grid, r+1, c, path);

    (rs > ds) ? path.push_back(Grid[r][c+1]) ? path.push_back(Grid[r+1][c]); // Recover path here. 
    return max(rs,ds)+Grid[r][c];

}
```

But I'm missing the point somewhere, because this results in multiple copies of the current element getting into the path when winding and unwinding from recursive calls.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you gave me this answer in an interview, I'd ask you how long this function takes, and how long a function to do this job *should* take.

Comment: There are considerably better ways to approach this problem: have you considered dynamic programming?

Comment: @MattTimmermans This function is exponential in time (2^(r+c))... Of course can probably reduce the time to O(m*n) using DP [?] but the idea was to get the logic right for recovering the path.

Comment: That's right.  When you come up with an O(n*m) algorithm, the path will be easier to recover.

Comment: actually there is no need to recover. Simply determine if the right or the down path is the better choice. Recursion is not needed at all.

Comment: @MattTimmermans Yes. Will implement the DP version of it, and post when done. But since this is an interview question, it was explicitly asked to recover path using recursion (even though not optimal).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the graph is encoded as a matrix, each vertex is supposed to be a pair, i.e. `std::pair<int, int>` that represents to `(row, column)` of the vertex.

Hence the path parameter should be declared as `vector<pair<int, int>>& path`

```
int getMaxPath(vector<vector<int> > Grid, int r, int c, vector<pair<int, int>>& path)
{
    ...
    (rs > ds) ? path.emplace_back(r, c+1) : path.emplace_back(r+1, c);
}
```

**EDIT**

the method is still incorrect because each recursive calls, including those that are not selected (optimal), will still put their results in the path. We need to pass to each recursive call a separate vector and only append it to ours if it is selected:

```
int getMaxPath(vector<vector<int> > Grid, int r, int c, vector<pair<int, int >> &path)
{
    if ((r > Grid.size() - 1) || (c > Grid[0].size() - 1))
        return 0;

    path.emplace_back(r, c);
    if (r == Grid.size() - 1 && c == Grid[0].size() - 1)
        return Grid[r][c];

    vector<pair<int, int >> rsPath, dsPath;
    int rs = getMaxPath(Grid, r, c + 1, rsPath);
    int ds = getMaxPath(Grid, r + 1, c, dsPath);

    if (rs > ds) {
        path.insert(path.end(), rsPath.begin(), rsPath.end());
        return rs + Grid[r][c];
    }
    else {
        path.insert(path.end(), dsPath.begin(), dsPath.end());
        return ds + Grid[r][c];
    }
}
```

p.s.: if, as you said, you want to capture the matrix weights instead of coordinate, you can adjust this but following the same logic to avoid those repetitions.

**Test**

```
int maxPath(vector<vector<int> > Grid, vector<pair<int, int>> &path)
{
    return getMaxPath(Grid, 0, 0, path);
}

int main()
{
        vector<vector<int> > mat{ { 5,0,8,12 },{ 11,16,9,13 },{ 10,2,15,300 },{ 3,14,18,19 } };
        vector<pair<int, int>>path;

        int result = maxPath(mat, path);
        cout << result << endl;

    for (auto it = path.begin(); it != path.end(); it++)
        std::cout << "(" << it->first << ", " << it->second << ")";
    system("pause"); return 0;
}
```

**Output**

> (0, 0)(1, 0)(1, 1)(1, 2)(2, 2)(2, 3)(3, 3)

Comment: Hi, I meant to recover the elements in the Grid... For e.g. the above grid would ideally result in this path ==> {5,11,16,9,15,300,19}.

Even if I tried your way, my problem would still persist. But instead of repeated elements, I'll get repeated locations. I should get {(0,0}, (1,0),(1,1),(1,2),(2,2),(2,3),(3,3)} but I get 1,0 
1,1 
2,1 
3,1 
3,2 
3,3 
2,2 
3,2 
3,3 
2,3 
3,3 
3,3 
1,2 
2,2 
3,2 
3,3 
2,3 
3,3 
3,3 
2,2 
2,3 
3,3 
3,3 
2,3 
3,3 
1,1 
1,2 
2,2 
3,2 
3,3 
2,3 
3,3 
3,3 
2,2 
2,3 
3,3 ....

Comment: ohh, I see! Indeed, the recursive calls, including those that are not taken, will still put their results in the path. I think that will be the case a long as we pass the `same vector by reference` to the recursive function. We need to pass to each a separate vector and only append it to ours if it is selected. I will edit my answer to suggest a solution

Comment: Thanks! This is incredibly detailed. I'll trace the calls and see how yours makes sense. Thanks for the help. Really appreciate it.